# Copy Constructors, Child Classes

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy

Some help to check the correctness of my code.

The fact that i'm copying a Child object using a Copy Constuctor from the Mother class, is it correct ? Or, should i implement a copy Constructor even for the Child ?

```
#include <iostream>
class Mother{

    public:

     Mother(int data):member(data){
     }

     Mother(Mother const& mother):member(mother.member){

     }

     Mother& operator=(Mother const& mother){

        if(this != &mother){
            member=mother.member;
        }

     }

     ~Mother(){
     }

     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Mother const& mother){
         out<<"Data :"<<mother.member<<std::endl;
         return out;
     }

    protected:

        int member;
};

class Child : public Mother{
   public:
       Child(int data):Mother(data){
       }
       ~Child(){
       }

   private:
    std::string chData;

};

int main()
{
    int a(42);
    Child child(a);
    Child copyChild = Child(a);

    std::cout<<copyChild;

    return 0;
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: I find it hard to follow what your question is. A big part of the reason is the writing -- the sentence structure leaves much to be desired. Maybe you could find someone to proofread your question? A more detailed explanation of why you are concerned about your issue might also help.

Comment: Maybe, knowing to read is also recommanded for a vital forum exchanges, my question was quite simple, i edited it anyway. All those questions are made to help all of us, I suggest, if you may, to channel this energy on something meaningful rather

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, the default `Child` copy constructor will do the *right thing* here. Or, are you not getting the result you want?

Comment: Yes, both reading and writing skills are required for forum exchanges (even if the forum exchanges are not vital). Writing in sentence fragments cripples the process. Your question might be simple, but you failed to express it in an easy-to-understand manner. I tried to give some pointers to make it more understandable, but if you refuse that advice, there is little I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using the CopyConstructor of the child class. It is implicitly created when the code is compiled even if you did not declare it.